# ANOVA for rate type dependent variables

Tags: anova, generalized-linear-model, psychology

In psychology, it is very common to measure rates (for example, error rates in a psychological task) and then submit them to an ANOVA test. Should that practice always be avoided? Should a generalized linear model always be preferred? What kind of problems can be generated by using ANOVA in such scenario?